# requestanimationframe is preventing custom cursor's transition

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, web-frontend

I'm using a **custom cursor**, which is working as expected.

I'm also using **requestanimationframe** to animate the screen on scroll.

**But my custom cursor's transition in css is lagging when I use requestanimationframe**.

React Js code

```
function App() {
  const [cursorX, setCursorX] = useState();
  const [cursorY, setCursorY] = useState();
  const [mouseIn, setMouseIn] = useState(true);
  const scrollWrapRef = useRef(null);
  const contentRef = useRef(null);
 
  let offset = 0;
  let currentPos = 0;

  useEffect(() => {
    const mouse = (e) => {
      setCursorX(e.clientX);
      setCursorY(e.clientY);
    };

    window.addEventListener("mousemove", mouse);

    const scrollWrap = scrollWrapRef.current;
    const content = contentRef.current;

    const smoothScroll = () => {
      offset += (window.pageYOffset - offset) * 0.04;
      const scroll = `translateY(-${offset}px) translateZ(0)`;
      scrollWrap.style.transform = scroll;
      requestAnimationFrame(smoothScroll);
    };

    smoothScroll();

    const callDistort = () => {
      const newPos = window.pageYOffset;
      const diff = newPos - currentPos;
      const speed = diff * 0.6;
      content.style.transform = `skewY(${speed}deg)`;
      currentPos = newPos;
      requestAnimationFrame(callDistort);
    };

    callDistort();

    return () => {
      cancelAnimationFrame(callDistort);
      cancelAnimationFrame(smoothScroll);
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", mouse);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App ">
       // custom cursor 
        <div
          className={cursor}
          style={{
            left: cursorX,
            top: cursorY,
          }}
        ></div>

      <div ref={scrollWrapRef}>
        <div ref={contentRef} className="section">
              <Intro />
              <About />
              <Projects />
              <Work />
              <Contact />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

css used

```
//custom cursor
.cursor {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 50%;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 100;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  // it works only if I don't use requestanimationframe
  transition: 0.15s linear, transform 0.8s ease-in-out;

//Scroll animation
.section {
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transition: transform 0.25s;
  will-change: transform;
}
```

you can check the output

**Only custom cursor**

[only custom cursor **screen recording**](https://mega.nz/file/xyowASCK#HwMw6nEAixVG2KlDhoqWbiYriBK_dQSs6u6rKaoR9lU)

https://noanimation.netlify.app/

**Both scroll animation and custom cursor**

[both scroll animation and custom cursor **screen recording**](https://mega.nz/file/ou5gDZAD#oTnlbJZrOtzwjqzvw0SSqvgI-h4SfX2pCP2x4vAyv8Y)

with requestanimationframe
https://requestanimationframereact.netlify.app/

**Custom cursor transition is not working smoothly if I use requestanimationframe**

Please help me.

Comment: both look almost identically rubbish to me (firefox ... doesn't look anything like what you want to do)

Comment: I have seen in firefox. The white ball movement is not smooth with requestanimationframe. That is the problem I'm facing.

Comment: it doesn't resize at all in firefox - perhaps you're using some CSS that firefox doesn't yet support? check using the *caniuse* website or MDN docs

Comment: In chrome and edge there is smooth movement of the white ball in https://noanimation.netlify.app/. But there is no smooth movement in https://requestanimationframereact.netlify.app/. That's the problem.

Comment: In the spec it says: "The frequency rate of events while the pointing device is moved is implementation-, device-, and platform-specific, but multiple consecutive mousemove events SHOULD be fired for sustained pointer-device movement, rather than a single event for each instance of mouse movement. Implementations are encouraged to determine the optimal frequency rate to balance responsiveness with performance." i.e. you may not get to hear about a move for a bit e.g. if the mouse is being moved rapidly. I don't think this frequency is changeable by you (but hopefully someone knows).

Comment: ...and like @JaromandaX I'm not seeing very smooth movement (Edge/WIndows10/reasonably powerful laptop) in either case.

Comment: Not sure of your issues, but using 2 concurrent animation loops doesn't seem right especially if targetting the same document flow.  Does things improve with a single animation loop.?

Comment: yes,  custom cursor is working smoothly, without scroll animation.  Scroll animation is working fine even with the custom cursor(but not this)

Comment: You just aren't going to get guaranteed smooth movement using mousemove - it will fire fairly promptly on the first mousemove, then if the user moves it quickly the moves are 'saved up' for a bigger move to show on the next firing. For true smoothness at any speed you are going to have to do the sampling yourself. Try it at every tenth of a second say to see if it can at least be more consistent if not totally smooth.

Comment: See the screen recordings that I have attached in the question. You can see the difference in the movement of the custom cursor(white ball)

Comment: Interesting - I see very similar jerky movement on both your examples which probably means I can't help any further, however, the fact remains that you can't guarantee smooth movement using mousemove as it's operation is up to the browser, not specified universally.